# delphi Berlin tabcontrol style

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I want to create a custom style for a `TTabControl`.

I succesfully changed the background color of the `TTabControl` itself, but I'm not able to do the same with the `TTabItem` objects. I added a `TRectangle` with the color properties set to my color preferences to the top `TTabItem` but it does not work.

Follows the `Structure` image:

[image]

This is what I want to achive:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can assure you that I did my homework. I searched for a solution at every source you can imaging. Not only that, but also made a bunch of experiencies. Non of them worked. Please take a look at the image I inserted just now, wich I hope, perfectly clarifies how I want my style to work. Thanks!

Comment: After so many views & not a single comment, I wonder if there is at all an answer to my question. Can it be that there is no way to get a `TTabControl` to work like this using just styles? Is it possible that at least something similar can be done? My goal was to put a `TTabControl` to work as pictured above, without the need of the `OnPaint` event. Can it be done? Thanks.